# Active Directory service account elevated privileges

Tags: powershell, aws-ssm, aws-directory-services

I am using AWS System Managers to execute PowerShell Scripts to my EC2 Active Directory instance to disable users.

In the PowerShell script, I am assuming a service account to perform the operations for me as such:

```
$ServiceAccountUsername= "username"
$ServiceAccountPassword= "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$ServiceAccountCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ServiceAccountUsername,$ServiceAccountPassword)
```

And then later on in the script:

```
$UserToDisable | Disable-ADAccount -Credential $ServiceAccountCredential
```

This works well when I am disabling `Domain Users` on the AD.

If I need to disable a `Domain Admin`, it fails with the following error

> Set-ADAccountExpiration : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation

I am also not allowed to give my service account the `Domain Admin` rights as it breaches the security policy of my company.

Is there any way I could disable Domain Admins using this service account? Are there any permissions (except Domain Admin) that I could give to the service account to make this work?

Comment: Modify the permissions on the OU where the admin accounts are to allow your service account to modify user accounts in that OU.

Comment: I gave the service account full control on the OU's security tab and it stil give me this error if i try to modify a Domain Admin's account.

Comment: Did you set the inheritance to "This object and all descendent objects"? Or was it "This object only"?

Comment: Delegating to child objects worked! Thanks :)

Comment: This might break at a later point as domain admins routinly break inheritance on objects. Look for AdminSDHolder to learn more about that (e.g. [Appendix C: Protected Accounts and Groups in Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory)).